# Oracle V$SQL field FIRST_LOAD_TIME shows older time than when query was launched

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I am running a series of stored procedures.

One of the stored procedures has been running awhile, so I used the following SQL to see what is going on on the Oracle server:

```
SELECT sid
      ,sess.process
      ,sess.status
      ,sess.username
      ,sess.schemaname,
      sql.sql_text,
      sql.*
  FROM v$session sess,
       v$sql     sql
 WHERE sql.sql_id(+) = sess.sql_id
   AND sess.type     = 'USER'
   ;
```

What seems weird here, is that when I look at the FIRST_LOAD_TIME field, the value shown here appears to be from BEFORE when the first of the stored procedures was launched... "2017-02-17/06:39:58"

So these procedures run in sequence... The last time they got hung up, I was pretty sure that I killed them using the following code:

```
select 
   session_id
from 
   dba_dml_locks;

select 
   sid,
   serial#
from 
   v$session
where 
   sid in ( 100)
;

alter system kill session '130,1333';
```

I even dropped and recreated the tables that these procedures populate, before re-running them.

Then, these procedures were launched again on Feb 21...  The Feb 17 date corresponds to the PREVIOUS time they were run....

I don't understand why the FIRST_LOAD_TIME field shows this date.. These have been running for 6 days now (since Feb 21) and I'm starting to wonder if I somehow failed to kill the previous run of these procedures....

Comment: You might be seeing the load time of the parent cursor as opposed the the child cursor?

Comment: How long does the same parent cursor stay in memory?  These procedures have been run over, and over.... long since before Feb 17.

Comment: Well, it's an LRU algorithm. So they could stay there a while. You could flush the shared pool. But, what exactly are you trying to do?